# How can I check array count changes in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want call some function when array count changes. Can I do this using **willSet**, or how can I check it

Comment: The obvious question here is, did you try to see if it works with `willSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current
>   value.
>
> You have the option to define either or both of these observers on a
>   property:
>
> - willSet is called just before the value is stored.
> - didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored. [source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

```
var arr = [1,2] {
    willSet {
        let newCount = newValue.count
        callMe(count: newCount)
    }
    didSet {
        let newCount = arr.count
        callMe(count: newCount)
    }
}

func callMe(count: Int) {
    print(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `count` of `newValue` and current `arr` in `willSet`, i.e.

```
var arr = [1, 2] {
    willSet {
        if newValue.count != arr.count {
            print("Count changed...")
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
arr.append(3) //Count changed...
arr[0] = 4
arr.remove(at: 0) //Count changed...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testArray : [Int] = [] {
    willSet{
        self.getCountBeforeAdd(index: testArray.count)
    }
    didSet {
        self.getCountAfterAdd(index: testArray.count)
    }
}

func getCountBeforeAdd(index:Int) {
    print("countBeforeAdd : \(index)")
}

func getCountAfterAdd(index:Int) {
    print("countAfterAdd : \(index)")
}

@IBAction func btnAddNew(_ sender: Any) {
    self.testArray.append(5)
}
```